# How to change the color of the junction between this "{}"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often have trouble identifying parts of a {} , so is there any way I can change the color like this?

I want it look like this

[image]

but mine look like this

[image]

Thank you
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlfIb.png)

Comment: the images are identical, but with different names

Comment: that is done in an extension, so change the settings of that thing

Comment: I don't see any difference between those pictures. I usually just open `{` on a different line, which makes it easier to identify later on.